# In terraform, Avoid recreating any resources if the vm has tag with specific key

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, hashicorp

1. Assume a terraform script, where it has instance and volume created.
2. After a day or two, from portal we have deleted a volume.
3. After a week, from terraform I would like to update the tags, instance type of that vm.

So above 3rd step should not recreate any volume or should not delete any existing tags attached to vm

Answer (score 1):

For those cases you can use `ignore_changes` and provide a list of anything you want to ignore when changed after created... **Most people will advise against this and I agree**, you should use this ignore as a last resource, your infrastructure changes should be ALL in terraform not manually in the portal or any other way, mixing manual changes with terraform is a recipe for disaster

```
resource "aws_instance" "hummingbot" {
  ami                  = data.aws_ami.foo.id
  instance_type        = "t2.medium"
  availability_zone    = "us-east-1a"
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.abc.name

  root_block_device {
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    volume_size           = "64"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  ebs_block_device {
    device_name           = "/dev/sdg"
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = "32"
    delete_on_termination = false
  }

  tags = {
    Terraformed = "true"
    Name        = "hummingbot"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [root_block_device, ebs_block_device, tags["tag_name"]]
  }
}
```

For the tags see what your options is `tags["tag_name"]` what you are asking "not delete any existing tags" you will have to specify what tags you want to ignore, I have not seen any option for wildcards there, there are requests for it:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5666
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24516

but not much traction there

---

Another way to ignore tags globally is using the `ignore_tags` Configuration Block on the AWS provider, you have a bit more flexible option there if it applies to multiple resources

```
provider "aws" {
  ignore_tags {
    keys = ["TagKey1"]
  }
}
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#ignore_tags-configuration-block

> The ignore_tags configuration block supports the following arguments:
>
> keys - (Optional) List of exact resource tag keys to ignore across all resources handled by this provider.
>
> key_prefixes - (Optional) List of resource tag key prefixes to ignore across all resources handled by this provider.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Helder-Sepulveda, 
I am already using ignore_changes for tags.
issues with them are.
1. user cannot add/update other tags, its kind of restricting him from using tags. 
2. user will not be able to assign new disks to the vm, if we restrict entire block.

please let me know, if there is any other plugin, that helps in resolving this issue.

Comment: That is all we got at this time ... for more flexibility upvote those github issues and leave your comments there ... but again I advise against using `ignore_changes` all your infrastructure should be "terraformed" without any manual hacks